# creating an org-capture template

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I am trying to create an org-capture template for a grocery list, but there seems to be no easy way to get the result I want, and I'm pretty bad at programming. So I was hoping that maybe someone has a solution.

I would like to have a template that does the following: I have a grocery.org file, that should have roughly the following structure:

```
* <Todays Date> 
- [ ] item 1 
- [ ] item 2
```

The template should check if there already is a headline with the current date. If so, just add an item to the list. If not, create the headline with the current date and start the list. 
I tried a couple of things with the standard tools of org-capture, like (file+headline) and (checkitem) and so on, but I really cant get that done.

I really hope someone can offer some help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to have things filed as

```
* <year>
** <month>
*** <day>
```

then using the `file+datetree` capture target instead of `file+headline` will work.  It files to the current date, creating it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I already tried that, but I would like the headline to be an active timestamp so that it shows up in my agenda. file+datetree seems to produce only normal headlines.

Answer (score 1):

To make the headline active in your agenda, you should add an active date to it. You can add a hook to org-capture to add a date.

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("g" "Grocery today" checkitem (file+datetree "~/org/grocery.org")
         "[ ] %?")))

(defun schedule-grocery-hook ()
  (if (string= (org-capture-get :description)
               "Grocery today")     ;Must match the description in the template
      (org-schedule 0 (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d"))))

(add-hook 'org-capture-before-finalize-hook 'schedule-grocery-hook)
```

This is what I get in grocery.org:

```
* 2017
** 2017-04 April
*** 2017-04-16 Sunday
    SCHEDULED: <2017-04-16 Sun>
    - [ ] abc
```

Besides, `org-datetree-add-timestamp` may be of your interest. But it will add timestamps to all datetree headlines.